# Who wrote a story called "Rule Golden"

Tags: story-identification

Details escape me, but the gist is of an alien travelling Earth, distributing an infection(?) that causes people to feel the result of their actions. E.g. I hit someone else, and feel the pain I caused.

Comment: There is this new thing called google where you just type name of something you are searching with few parameters like "rule golden sci fi book" and believe it or not second link takes you to pretty much same amazon page @Richard gave you :D

Comment: Yeah, but "rule golden story" did not give me anything immediately useful - until I submitted this question.

Comment: I was just trolling a bit :) But try when you are in need of searching something to broaden your parameters like I did. Use genre, year, what is it. It can help you a lot without having to wait for someone to answer you :)

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=B36z4cUErAs This was a funnier interpretation :D

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is the Damon Knight story ["Rule Golden"](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?40978), described here on [Amazon](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0380436469)

> *The first story is about the alien that emits a gas that forces us to
> obey the Golden Rule: If you kill someone, you will drop dead. If you
> hurt someone, you will suffer the same injury. At the conclusion of the story,
> the earthmen conclude that they have become "more human".*

You can read a large chunk [here on google books](https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=wclcFvCJOsEC&pg=PT34&lpg=PT34&dq=%22Rule%20Golden%22%20and%20knight%20and%20gas&source=bl&ots=h0-wdP9qNX&sig=HQATvU6dzMFDqyCenlqXQoPGzs8&hl=en&sa=X&redir_esc=y#v=onepage&q=%22Rule%20Golden%22%20and%20knight%20and%20gas&f=false)